# Как размещать элементы приложения из центра?

Tags: android

Центрирую форму ввода текста и пытаюсь разместить еще одну форму снизу и одну сверху. Но они съезжают вверх, в чем проблема?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="640dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity"
    android:background="#ffffff">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: android:layout_marginTop="70dp" уберите отовсюду

Comment: А как тогда делать отступы от центральной формы?

Comment: у вас разметку можно сделать проще, щас накидаю

Answer (score 3):

Вот так можно. Добавьте атрибуты, которые Вам нужны

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/second"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/third"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы формы одинаково отображались на планшетах и смартфонах, обязательно посередине экрана(по вертикали и горизонтали).

Comment: android:gravity="center_horizontal" в LinearLayout добавьте, будет одинаково везде, только вот 300dp будет различаться на некоторых девайс, ну здесь другой вопрос уже.
Если хотите чтоб вообще в центре были, то android:gravity="center".
Если у Вас не будет больше элементов, то эта разметка будет лучшем вариантов, чем Ваша +1.

Comment: android:gravity="center" как раз то что мне было нужно. Благодарю.